# How can I specify upload server in pypi upload?

Tags: pypi, python-packaging, pypiserver

Suppose I have a **`.pypirc`** file as,

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi
    test2
    test3
    test4

[pypi]
repository: https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
username: username_1
password: passme_1
[test2]
repository: url_1
username: username_1
password: passme_1
[test3]
repository: url_2
username: username_1
password: passme_1
[test4]
repository: url_3
username: username_1
password: passme_1
```

How can I upload to **`test4`** profile without specifying **`--repository-url`** ?

Answer (score 1):

`twine upload --help`:

```
…
-r REPOSITORY, --repository REPOSITORY
   The repository (package index) to upload the package
   to. Should be a section in the config file (default:
   pypi). (Can also be set via TWINE_REPOSITORY
   environment variable.)
…
```

So you should run `twine upload -r test4`.